# Spring boot to work with legacy data beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a legacy spring module which has data bean definitions from dataSource to transactionManager( based on C3P0 and Hibernate). I want to re-use all those bean definitions in Spring Boot app. The Spring boot build files are generated by default from initializr. While running, I encountered the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Generic.class]: @Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition: Generic bean: class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=close; defined in class path resource*
```

dataSource is a bean inside data-beans.xml.
I have imported the xml bean definition with @Configuration :

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:data-beans.xml"})
public class XmlConfig {
}
```

Comment: If you're moving to Boot, you can probably start by incrementally removing the hand-written definitions that Boot provides automatic templates for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to exclude autconfiguration on datasource:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, TransactionAutoConfiguration.class})
```

You can also set the following property to suppress the warning but it is not good practice:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```